# Special Moving Average

Tags: python, pandas

I want to predict the direction towards which the price will change.
The term price is used to refer to the mid-price of a stock, which is defined as the mean between the best bid price and
best ask price at time t:

[image]

This is a virtual value for the price since no order can happen at
that exact price, but predicting its upwards or downwards movement
provides a good estimate of the price of the future orders. A set of
discrete choices must be constructed from our data to use as targets
for our classification model. Simply using p(t) > p(t+k) to
determine the direction of the mid-price would introduce unmanageably
amount of noise, since the smallest change would be registered as an
upward or downward movement.

The mean of the previous k mid-prices, denoted by m_b, and the mean of the next k mid-prices, denoted by m_a, are defined as:

[image]

Here is a sample :

```
0        2015-03-31 09:30:00.233  2.4645
1        2015-03-31 09:30:00.233  2.4634
2        2015-03-31 09:34:44.116  2.5363
3        2015-03-31 09:34:44.116  2.5434
4        2015-03-31 09:36:38.535  2.5356
5        2015-03-31 09:36:38.535  2.5432
6        2015-03-31 09:36:38.537  2.5463
7        2015-03-31 09:36:38.537  2.5432
8        2015-03-31 09:45:10.512  2.5274
9        2015-03-31 09:45:10.512  2.5262
10       2015-03-31 09:45:10.523  2.5299
11       2015-03-31 09:45:10.529  2.5234
12       2015-03-31 09:45:10.531  2.5276
13       2015-03-31 09:45:10.568  2.5212
14       2015-03-31 09:45:10.569  2.5262
15       2015-03-31 09:45:10.635  2.5143
16       2015-03-31 09:45:10.684  2.5267
17       2015-03-31 09:45:10.686  2.5212
18       2015-03-31 10:00:02.111  2.5213
19       2015-03-31 10:00:02.111  2.5298
20       2015-03-31 10:00:02.112  2.5212
21       2015-03-31 10:00:02.381  2.5263
22       2015-03-31 10:00:02.472  2.5212
23       2015-03-31 10:00:02.486  2.5298
24       2015-03-31 10:00:02.524  2.5298
25       2015-03-31 10:00:04.026  2.5270
26       2015-03-31 10:06:54.546  2.5212
27       2015-03-31 10:06:54.558  2.5234
28       2015-03-31 10:06:54.558  2.5253
29       2015-03-31 10:06:54.566  2.5234
```

Aat any time, I want to compute m_a and m_b, but I don't know how to do it with pandas or numpy. Assuming the horizon k=5, how could I code those two special moving averages with python? So I need two functions, i.e. `leftmovingaverage()` and `rightmovingaverage()` and display two columns next to the price column with name `M_A` and `M_B`.

**Example :**

Image we have 1000 time data. And set k = 600, then you can compute m_a from k=590~600 and m_b from k = 601~610. Everything is well explain in the following link : http://poseidon.csd.auth.gr/papers/PUBLISHED/CONFERENCE/pdf/2017/2017_CBI_CNNLOB.pdf.

Comment: I want to make sure some things. 1. In the formula of `m_b(t)`, why does k start from 0? On top of that you are diving by `k`. So technically, you are adding `k+1` terms and dividing by `k`. Is that correct? 2. In your example, how can you compute `m_a` from t = 590 if k = 600? By the way, in your example, I think it should be `t = 590 ~ 600` instead of `k = 590 ~ 600`.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar Loot at the following link : https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fposeidon.csd.auth.gr%2Fpapers%2FPUBLISHED%2FCONFERENCE%2Fpdf%2F2017%2F2017_CBI_CNNLOB.pdf&h=ATOH-1NxBXIXGTKFh5wCiiAuex_UdNoCj_L_DMTh137zdgSp_FeDlHImR0Vggx1dXOkZgvSfD6MfVPBYJ3Dw_-8B7R7AKSsyTzX8hAP7WUmjnQ. Everything is wel explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def moving_average(df, col_name='Price', k=3):
    ma_cols = []
    mb_cols = []
    temp_df = DataFrame()

    for i in range(0, k+1):
        ma_col = 'M_A_{}'.format(i)
        ma_cols.append(ma_col)
        mb_col = 'M_B_{}'.format(i)
        mb_cols.append(mb_col)
        temp_df[ma_col] = df[col_name].shift(i)
        temp_df[mb_col] = df[col_name].shift(-i)

    df['M_A'] = temp_df[ma_cols].mean(axis=1, skipna=True, numeric_only=True)
    df['M_B'] = temp_df[mb_cols].mean(axis=1, skipna=True)
    print (df)
    return df

moving_average(df)
```

For both summation, both index start at i=1 and the sum is divided by k+1 instead of k